# Where to create my objects in a windows form app?

Tags: c#, object, encapsulation, winapp

I'm trying to create an object in my windows form app but if I create it in the constructor, then I can't access it in the entire app...(Like the events) In the code below the Time1 isn't available. I'll be happy to hear from you...

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ClockApp
{
    public partial class ClockApp : Form
    {
        public ClockApp()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ClockApp Time1 = new ClockApp();
        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void ClockApp_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void btnOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //ClockApp Time1 = new ClockApp();
            Time1.getHour = Convert.ToInt16(txtHour.Text);
            Time1.getMin = Convert.ToInt16(txtMin.Text);
            Time1.getSec = Convert.ToInt16(txtSec.Text);
            if(rbUniversal.Checked == true)
            {
                Time1.ToUniversal();
            }else if(rbStandard.Checked == true)
            {
                Time1.ToStandard();
            }
            else
            {
                lblTime.Text = "NOT Working...";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The code below is my class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ClockApp
{
    public partial class ClockApp : Form
    {
        // Fields
        private int Hour;
        private int Min;
        private int Sec;

        // Properties
        public int getHour
        {
            get
            {
                return Hour;
            }
            set
            {
                if(value > 23 && value < 0)
                {
                    Hour = 23;
                }
                else
                {
                    Hour = value;
                }
            }
        }
        public int getMin
        {
            get
            {
                return Min;
            }
            set
            {
                if(value > 59 && value < 0)
                {
                    Min = 59;
                }
                else
                {
                    Min = value;
                }
            }
        }
        public int getSec
        {
            get
            {
                return Sec;
            }
            set
            {
                if(value > 59 && value < 0)
                {
                    Sec = 59;
                }
                else
                {
                    Sec = value;
                }
            }
        }

        // Constructors


        // Methods
        // ToUniversal()
        public void ToUniversal()
        {
            lblTime.Text = Hour.ToString() + ":" + Min.ToString() + ":" + Sec.ToString();
        }

        // ToStandard()
        public void ToStandard()
        {
            if(Hour > 12)
            {
                int[] Modifier = new int[12];
                for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
                {
                    Modifier[i] = i + 13;
                    if (Hour == Modifier[i])
                    {
                        Hour = i+1;
                        lblAMPM.Text = "PM";
                    }

                }
                lblTime.Text = Hour.ToString() + ":" + Min.ToString() + ":" + Sec.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                lblAMPM.Text = "AM";
                lblTime.Text = Hour.ToString() + ":" + Min.ToString() + ":" + Sec.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have some serious design flows...why your ClockApp is derived from Forms class? instead write those methods as Getters and access theire return value from your form application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You dont need to create a new instance of `ClockApp` in the constructor.

  - Remove that line.
- The field (or whatever) 'Time1' is not needed. Remove 'Time1.' completely form your code:

  - `Time1.getHour = Convert.ToInt16(txtHour.Text);` => `getHour = Convert.ToInt16(txtHour.Text);`
  - `Time1.ToUniversal();` => `ToUniversal();`
  - and so on.

That should make your code at least compilable.

---

**Bugs:**

- `value > 23 && value < 0` is always false. You have to use `||` instead of `&&`.
- same for `value > 59 && value < 0`

---

**Code conventions:**

I know you just starting with c#, but please check the common coding convention to improve the readabilty:

- Properties: first letter is capitalized
- Fiels: first letter is not capitalized
- Do not start you propery name with 'get'. Just `Hour`, `Min` or `Sec` is perfect.

Comment: It started working... I really appreciate your help JNS :-)